# Android Studio: Block comment style

Tags: android, android-studio, block-comments

Block comment style in **Eclipse** (`write /* and press Enter`)

```
/*
 *  Hello World
 */
```

Block comment style in **Android Studio**

```
/*
    Hello World
 */
```

How can I make my Android Studio block comments look like the one in Eclipse? Couldn't find anything in the settings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a **Live Template** to do that.

Follow these steps:

1. Open **Settings** (`File -> Settings`) and go to `Live Templates` (under `Editor`)
2. Click the green `+` (top right) and choose `1. Live Template`
3. Enter `/*` as abbreviation and add a description (if desired)
4. Add the following to the `Template text:`

   ```
   /*
    * $END$
    */
   ```
5. Set `Expand with` to `ENTER`.
6. Click `Define` (highlighted in blue at the bottom) and select areas where you would like the template to be applicable (Java, for example).
7. Save settings by clicking `Apply` or `OK`

Now you can type `/*` followed by `ENTER` to insert the desired code :)

Comment: That is one stylish answer. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

The closet way of reproducing your result would be to type `/**` and press `Enter`. This will produce javadocs comments of the form:

```
/**
 * Hello World
 */
```

Then you can delete the second asterisk from the beginning.

Comment: Works but it's not exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/** write your comment here **/
```

After writing when you hover on left bar, it will show you **toggle rendered view**, When you click on it.

It will change the comment into below UI
[image: Comment look like this when we click on left honor]